# R get rows where all values are NaN

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to get all rows where specific values (here RATIO1 and RATIO 2) are NaN an keep them.

consider a data frame like

```
data.frame(ID=c(1,2,4,6,7),RATIO1=c(NaN,NaN,0.2,9.5,6), 
           RATIO2=c(NaN,NaN,0.5,NaN,6), RATIO3=c(0.3,0.2,4,NaN,5))

 ID RATIO1 RATIO2 RATIO3
1  1    NaN    NaN    0.3
2  2    NaN    NaN    0.2
3  4    0.2    0.5      4
4  6    9.5    NaN    NaN
5  7      6      6      5
```

I want it to look like this

```
 ID RATIO1 RATIO2 RATIO3
1  1    NaN    NaN    0.3
2  2    NaN    NaN    0.2
```

I could make it using is.na() or complete.cases () <- this will delete the rows.

Thx

Comment: lets say: ratios are from sepcific origin and i would like to get the origin specific "rows" eg for ratio3 -> ratio2 and ratio 1 should be NaN (e.g. not found in sample)

Comment: Ok, but you do realize that that you've coerced everything to character (or factors) here, right?

Comment: ya true, sorry mistake in a hurry any idea? : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you really are dealing with `NaN` and not some arbitrary character value, try something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,4,6,7),RATIO1=c(NaN,NaN,0.2,9.5,6), RATIO2=c(NaN,NaN,0.5,NaN,6), RATIO3=c(0.3,0.2,4,NaN,5))
> dat[is.nan(dat$RATIO1) & is.nan(dat$RATIO2),]
  ID RATIO1 RATIO2 RATIO3
1  1    NaN    NaN    0.3
2  2    NaN    NaN    0.2
```

`is.finite` might also prove useful if you're doing this sort of thing often.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possibility, using [`apply()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html) to examine the rows one at a time and determine whether they are fully composed of `NaN`s:

```
df[apply(df[2:3], 1, function(X) all(is.nan(X))),]
#   ID RATIO1 RATIO2 RATIO3
# 1  1    NaN    NaN    0.3
# 2  2    NaN    NaN    0.2
```

Comment: I like this for being a solution that isn't tied only to specific columns.

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced solution based on this from Josh O'Briens.

```
df[rowSums(is.nan(as.matrix(df[2:3])))>1,]
#
# as.matrix because is.nan requires matrix  (but is.na doesn't)
# rowSums for speed gain
#
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,4,6,7),RATIO1=c(NaN,NaN,0.2,9.5,6), 
                   RATIO2=c(NaN,NaN,0.5,NaN,6), RATIO3=c(0.3,0.2,4,NaN,5))

df[is.nan(df$RATIO1) & is.nan(df$RATIO2),]

  ID RATIO1 RATIO2 RATIO3
1  1    NaN    NaN    0.3
2  2    NaN    NaN    0.2
```

Comment: But that would keep rows that contain `NA`s (and not just `NaN`s) in columns 2 and 3 ...

Comment: You're right! I missed that as well as subset the data.frame incorrectly... I've updated my answer, which is no different than joran's answer below.